# Why does eso-pic turn off the Tikz text opacity?

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, eso-pic

Without `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[color=red,text opacity=0.25,rotate=45,font=\fontsize{150}{30}\selectfont]
        at (current page.center) {Draft};
\end{tikzpicture}
watermark:
\end{document}
```

I get the opacity that I want:
[image: Correct Opacity]

But when I add `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{eso-pic}
        \AddToShipoutPicture{
%            \ifnum\value{page}>1
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                    \node[color=red,text opacity=0.1,rotate=45,font=\fontsize{150}{30}\selectfont]
                        at (current page.center) {Draft};
                \end{tikzpicture}
%            \fi
        }
\begin{document}
watermark:
\end{document}
```

I seem to lose the opacity from Tikz:
[image: No Opacity]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems fine to me. What distribution are you using? and Package versions?

Comment: @azetina should i just be looking in the log file?  it says pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 and pdflatex 2012.3.28 and LaTeX2e 2005/12/01, eso-pic 2006/07/14 v1.1d, tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 et cetera

Comment: By distribution I mean MiKTeX or TeXLive. My packages are eso-pic 2013/10/06 v2.0d eso-pic (RN) and tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142) so probably it is why you are getting that result. Try updating the package and see what happens.

Comment: @azetina oh, i'm working on a controlled system, so unfortunately i can't update the package.  i'm not positive how to tell what distribution i have but MiKTeX doesn't show up in the log file.  two things in my log file report as configurations of TeXLive, so i presume i have that.

Comment: You can probably download the packages independently and place them where you are compiling or try sharelatex.com.

Comment: @azetina it looks fine on sharelatex.com, so i guess i'll have to try installing locally

Comment: By the way, the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package already offers the functionality in your example. All you need is `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[angle=45]{background}

\begin{document}
watermark:
\end{document}` (compile twice).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina that didn't show up in any of my searches for making watermarks, and it looks like it would be great.  i'm able to import the package but unfortunately can't get any of the package options or user commands to work.  i assume it has to do with versions as well, but this would be handy for the next person that searches about this subject.

Comment: Caused by outdated packages: I'm afraid that is tricky to help with beyond 'update'